# What happens if @WorkerThread annonated function calls another function in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, worker-thread

**Which thread the subsequently called functions are executed?**

You may consider a function like the getNewsFeed() function inside the repository class given below -

```kotlin
@Singleton
class NewsFeedRepository @Inject constructor(
    private val networkDataSource: NetworkDataSource,
    private val diskDataSource: DiskDataSource
) {

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun getNewsFeed(): NewsResponse {
        return try {
            val news = networkDataSource.getNewsFeed()
            diskDataSource.updateCache(news)
            NewsResponse(news = news)

        } catch (ex: Exception) {

            NewsResponse(
                news = diskDataSource.getNews(),
                errorMessage = ex.message
            )

        }
    }
}
```

I called the getNewsFeed() function from ViewModel using kotlin coroutine as given below -

```
@HiltViewModel
class MainViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: NewsFeedRepository
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _newsResponse = MutableLiveData<NewsResponse>()
    val newsResponse: LiveData<NewsResponse>
        get() = _newsResponse

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            _newsResponse.value = repository.getNewsFeed()
        }
    }

}
```

I tried to use Dispatchers.IO as well but I couldn't update livedata value hence I had to use @WorkerThread.

Comment: I am not familiar with the `@WorkerThread` annotation, but you can avoid it altogether though. By default `viewModelScope` is using `Dispatchers.Main.immediate`, since you want to offload your network request to a background thread you can do it as follows, `viewModelScope.launch { _newsResponse.value = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) { repository.getNewsFeed() } }`. Basically you're updating livedata on the main thread, but the value is being fetched on the background thread.

Comment: annotating a method with `@WorkerThread` does not magically make it run on a different thread, it's simply a hint for the developer using that method.

Comment: @J.Grbo will the subsequently called functions by repository.getNewsFeed() also be executed in IO thread?

Comment: @Vic Everything within `withContext's` curly braces is executed on a background thread (IO thread pool). If you will ever execute those repository functions on background threads, you can wrap their content inside `withContext(dispatcher)`, where `dispacther` is also injected into the repository, and then in production you can inject a `Dispatchers.IO` as a `dispatcher`.

Comment: Thanks @J.Grbo and Adrian K. I got it.

Comment: @J.Grbo viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            _newsResponse.postValue(repository.getNewsFeed())
        }                   In this way I will the repository.getNewsFeed() be executed in main thread or worker thread?

Comment: @Vic Probably on the main thread due to postValue posting the task to the main thread. You could do it as follows `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { val newsFeed = repository.getNewsFeed() _newsResponse.postValue(newsFeed) }`

Comment: @J.Grbo I tried using Thread.currentThread().toString() inside repository.getNewsFeed() function and displaying that value using a Toast. It showed Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-3,5,main] in both ways we discussed. But if we remove Dispatchers.IO from the way you advised it showed Thread[main,5,main]. So I guess it runs in worker thread if use Dispachers.IO right? Maybe postvalue simply updates it inside UI thread after whole process inside viewModelScope.launch finishes?

Comment: @AdrianK do you have any idea regarding the above mentioned points?